# Finding the cube root of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

EDIT.

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix} -41 & 231 \\ 66 & 223\end{pmatrix}$ and let $X\in M_2(\mathbb{C})$ s.t. $X^3
=A$. That follows is a little computational reasoning.

1. Show (without any calculation) that, necessarily, $X$ is in the form $aI+bA$, where $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$.
2. Show that $\det(A-x^3I)$ admits, as a factor, a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ of degree $2$ (during a first step, work in $\mathbb{Z}/29\mathbb{Z}$).
3. Find the solutions $X\in M_2(\mathbb{Q})$.

Comment: Hint: Can you diagonalize the matrix?

Comment: It is pretty easy to find the eigenvalues of a $2\times 2$ matrix since one has only to solve a quadratic equation for the characteristic roots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above matrix $M$ is diagonalizable, so write $D=SMS^{-1}$. Then it is easy to find a matrix $D'$ with $D'^3=D$. Then $(S^{-1}D'S)^3=S^-1{}DS=M$.

Even the direct computation gives a solution. Let 
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then $A^3=M$ says that 
\begin{align*}
a^3 + 2abc + bcd + 41 & = 0,\\
a^2b + abd + b^2c + bd^2 - 231 & = 0\\
a^2c + acd + bc^2 + cd^2 - 66 & = 0\\
abc + 2bcd + d^3 - 223 & =0
\end{align*}
Buchberger's algorithm immediately gives several solutions, e.g.
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} -3 & 7 \\ 2 & 5 \end{pmatrix}.
$$